# i have accidently deleted my Service accounts on gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

i have accidently deleted my Service accounts on gcp that was created on the time of compute API enabling , now i disabled  and enabled it many times but its not creating new Service accounts .

now i am getting this error :

> services-exploring-project)$ gcloud compute instances create mytest
>
> Did you mean zone [asia-southeast1-b] for instance: [mytest] (Y/n)? YERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource: - The resource 'does_not_exist@invalid-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found.
>
> deactivate the compute API
>
> services-exploring-project)$ gcloud compute instances create mytest
>   Did you mean zone [asia-southeast1-b] for instance: [mytest] (Y/n)?  Y
>   ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
>    - The resource 'does_not_exist@invalid-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the Compute Engine default service account back after its accidental deletion you must contact the Compute Engine team as it’s explained in the [following documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_default_service_account).

Meanwhile, if you want to keep working on that project, you can create another service account and associate it with the same role, for example, that the Compute Engine default service account had.

This role, named editor, is of the primitive type and you can find more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_role_definitions).

In this way, you will be able to create Compute Engine instances. Just follow this steps:

Set some variables;

```
zone=us-central1-b

PROJECT_NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID --format="value(projectNumber)")

sa_name=no-clone-$PROJECT_NUMBER-compute
```

Create a new service account and update project IAM policy by adding to it a binding between that service account and the primitive role explained above;

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create $sa_name --display-name="Work around deletion of Compute Engine default service account"

sa=$(gcloud iam service-accounts list --filter=$sa_name --format="value(email)") 

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID --member="serviceAccount:$sa" --role="roles/editor"
```

Create a new instance with the newly-created service account and test it out;

```
gcloud compute instances create test01 --zone=$zone --quiet --service-account=$sa

gcloud compute ssh test01 --zone=$zone --command="cat /etc/os-release"
```

For more background in Identity and Access Management refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview).

Comment: i tried creating new one with the same permissions required to create a vm but its still showing the same error.

Comment: The script I’ve posted in the answer was tested and it's working. The only steps that are missing is the enabling of the Compute Engine Service for the first time and the deletion of the Compute Engine default service account created by the previous action.

Comment: Check if the Compute Engine Service is enabled using the command `gcloud services list --enabled --filter=compute.googleapis.com`.
If it's not, enable it with `gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com`. And then proceed with the steps explained the answer.
If you got any errors, post them along with the commands you have used.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`gcloud app repair`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/repair):

> gcloud beta app repair - restores required App Engine features to the current application

Comment: its not working , to repair the features it require the same account that i had accidentally deleted .             services-exploring-project)$ gcloud beta app repair
Repairing the app [services-exploring-project]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.repair) App [services-exploring-project:repair] not found: Could not find Application "services-exploring-project".
chandan_15cse14@cloudshell:~ (services-exploring-project)$